# Iterating individual fields from a foreach statement in PHP

Tags: php, joomla

Let's see...where to start here?  Okay, yes I am working in Joomla and trying to modify some code inside a Joomla Component called JomSocial.  My failure to do this is based not on understanding what's going on in the component or the Joomla system, just that I cannot read the PHP code well enough to modify what's happening.

Essentially, this script outputs a Definition List of all the bits of profile information from a selected user.  This is great, but I need to re-use this code in a different section of the site where I would only like to use one or two fields, not the whole array of User profile fields.

I am including most of the code from the script here, but I truly feel the answer I seek is far simpler and is just general PHP knowledge.  Specifically, what would I do to echo the arrays of fields that the foreach statement is manifesting.

If this something for which any of you feel inclined to help, awesome.
If this has been resolved in the general PHP questions section, a link would also be awesome.  I tried searching the PHP answers for something like this, but none seem to be doing what I am asking here.

Again, all I really need is to able to do what this code is doing, just doing it by iterating individual fields, not by dumping out every field.

Thanks Muchly,
Thomas Harrison
*I stare at you with awe.*

```
<?php foreach( $profile['fields'] as $groupName => $items ): 

        // Gather display data for the group. If there is no data, we can 
        // later completely hide the whole segment
        $hasData = false;
        ob_start();

        ?>
        <div class="cProfile-About">
        <?php if( $groupName != 'ungrouped' ): ?>
        <h4><?php echo JText::_( $groupName ); ?></h4>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <dl class="profile-right-info">
            <?php foreach( $items as $item ): ?>
                <?php
                if( CPrivacy::isAccessAllowed( $my->id , $profile['id'] , 'custom' , $item['access'] ) )
                {
                    // There is some displayable data here
                    $hasData = true;
                ?>
                    <dt><?php echo JText::_( $item['name'] ); ?></dt>
                    <?php if( !empty($item['searchLink']) && is_array($item['searchLink']) ): ?>
                        <dd>
                            <?php foreach($item['searchLink'] as $linkKey=>$linkValue): ?>
                            <?php $item['value'] = $linkKey; ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $linkValue; ?>"><?php echo CProfileLibrary::getFieldData( $item ) ?></a><br />
                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                        </dd>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <dd>
                            <?php if(!empty($item['searchLink'])) :?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $item['searchLink']; ?>"> 
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php echo CProfileLibrary::getFieldData( $item ); ?>

                            <?php if(!empty($item['searchLink'])) :?>
                                </a> 
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </dd>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <?php 
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // We would only display the profile data in the group if there is actually some
    // data to be displayed
    if( $hasData ):
        echo $html;
        $noData = false;
    endif;
    endforeach; 



if ($noData)
    echo ($isMine) ? JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_PROFILES_SHARE_ABOUT_YOURSELF') : JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_PROFILES_NO_INFORMATION_SHARE');
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (if I understand correctly) you should just need to do something like:

```
$profile['fields']['name'] //Replace 'name' with whatever field name you are after
```

You can `echo` this or store it in another variable for later use if you wish.

You can access any of the other fields too just by changing the `'name'` part of the code as long as you know what the field name is.

To find out all of the data stored in `$profile['fields']` you can do `print_r($profile['fields']);` which will print all of the fields in this format:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Fred Bloggs
    [Age] => 23
)
```

You can then use anything in the square brackets in place of the `'name'` to get that fields value.

***EDIT***

With your pastebin example (http://pastebin.com/UbiHbDsL) say you wanted to access the value of line 21:

```
[0] => Male
```

You would use this:

```
$profile['fields']['Basic Information'][0]['options'][0]
```

This basically is going deeper into the array structure for each square bracket set. `Echo`ing the above would output:

> Male

Comment: I will try this and let you know my results.  Thanks!

Comment: Array
(
    [Basic Information] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [type] => select
                    [ordering] => 2
                    [published] => 1
                    [min] => 0
                    [max] => 0
                    [name] => I am | We are
                    [tips] => Select gender
                    [visible] => 1
                    [required] => 1
                    [searchable] => 1
                    [registration] => 1
                    [options] => Array
                        (

Comment: Output is large.  How can i attach here?

Comment: Added the Output to the original Post

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the output in your original post?

Comment: I think StackOverflow said it needed to be approved to be made public.

Comment: It shouldn't need peer reviewing if you've edited your own post. Put a cop on http://pastebin.com/ and post a link here.

Comment: It looks like you tried to edit my post rather than yours, thats why it was needing to be peer reviewed. Anyway, I've made an edit to show you how to access array values.